# Can not create super user, because foreign key can not be null

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, createuser

How to assign foreign key value, when creating super user in Django?

I want to make new superuser using python manage.py createsuperuser command, but I get an error:
ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Company: Company object (1)>]>": "Worker.company" must be a "Company" instance.

Here is the code:

```
class CompanyAccountType(models.Model):
    accountTypeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    accountTypeValue = models.IntegerField()

class Company(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    companyAccountType = models.ForeignKey(CompanyAccountType, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    
    
class MyAccounManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
        )
        
        #I tried this for testing (real I would like to send id throught request), but I get error 
        #ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Company: Company object (1)>]>": "Worker.company" must be a "Company" instance.
        companyObj = Company.objects.filter(id=1)
        user.company = companyObj
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(username=username, 
                            password = password,
                            )                        
        #user.company.id = 1
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Worker(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, default="user")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="password")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)  #blank=True
    workerName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    workerProfileImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default = "images/defaultUser.png", null = True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['company']

    objects = MyAccounManager()

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: try to change `filter` (which returns an object *set*) by `get` (to have one single object): `companyObj = Company.objects.get(id=1)`

Comment: Thanks, I think it helps. But now I get some other error, it is again some other foreign key problem (i want to generate token) "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`authtoken_token`, CONSTRAINT `authtoken_token_user_id_35299eff_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')"

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to handle this new error

Comment: Thanks, I would like just to know if I am on good way.
I would like to have standard super user in Django app. On the other side, I have to make login system and authentication system for "users of app". So do I have to inheritate User class with my models class Worker or I can make use tokens without that. I think that this would make that everyone can access to system as super user, because every user I make would be super user, or I have to give him some privileges? I am pretty new in Django, so it is really confusing for me? Thanks in advance.